# Android SQLite crashes when letter is used

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

My android code is saving strings to an SQlite database, and it only works if i use numbers in it. It crashes if i use letters.

This is the code:

```
final SQLiteDatabase mydatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("localdatabase",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
mydatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SPENT(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, date VARCHAR, value VARCHAR,label1 " +
    "VARCHAR,label2 VARCHAR,label3 VARCHAR,label4 VARCHAR,label5 VARCHAR);");

String  uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
long unixTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;

EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
EditText et3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
EditText et4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
EditText et5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
EditText et6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);

String str1 = et1.getText().toString();
String str2 = et2.getText().toString();
String str3 = et3.getText().toString();
String str4 = et4.getText().toString();
String str5 = et5.getText().toString();
String str6 = et6.getText().toString();

if (str1.isEmpty()){str1 = "0";};
if (str2.isEmpty()){str2 = "0";};
if (str3.isEmpty()){str3 = "0";};
if (str4.isEmpty()){str4 = "0";};
if (str5.isEmpty()){str5 = "0";};
if (str6.isEmpty()){str6 = "0";};

String Msg = "WriteNewLoan,"+userName+","+unixTime+","+str1+","+str2+","
    +str3+","+str4+","+str5+","+str6+","+uniqueID+","+base64PW;

mydatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO LOAN VALUES("+unixTime+","+str1+","+str2
    +","+str3+","+str4+","+str5+","+str6+");");
```

And this is the error in catlog:

```
Process: com.spendingtracker.readdeo.spendingtracker, PID: 21859
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "2hvg" (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO SPENT (date,value,label1,label2,label3,label4,label5) VALUES(1475224906,0,0,2hvg,0,0,0);
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1674)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1605)
    at com.spendingtracker.readdeo.spendingtracker.MainActivity$4.onClick(MainActivity.java:242)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21156)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

The error points to this line:

```
mydatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO SPENT (date,value,label1,label2,label3,label4,label5) VALUES("+unixTime+","+str1+","+str2
    +","+str3+","+str4+","+str5+","+str6+");");
```

The unrecognized token: "2hvg" is a string from an EditText that makes it crash if it is not containing only numbers.

Can you please tell me why is this cannot work with letters? I tried to replace VARCHAR with TEXT, but nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First the solution.**

The problem in your query is that you are missing the escape values, as said from others answers.

So add an `'` before and after each string:

```
mydatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO SPENT (date,value,label1,label2,label3,label4,label5) VALUES('"+unixTime+"','"+str1+"','"+str2
                        +"','"+str3+"','"+str4+"','"+str5+"','"+str6+"');");
```

---

**Now, said this, I have to say that the method you are using is not the best way for it, both for security reasons and for code semplicity**

If you need to insert datas, please use the classic `SqliteDatabase Insert function` [here is the doc about it](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)):

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("date", myDateString);
values.put("value", myValueString);
...//and so on

db.insert(tableName, null, values);
```

and you are done. hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape your String with '.

```
mydatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO SPENT (date,value,label1,label2,label3,label4,label5) VALUES('"+unixTime+"','"+str1+"','"+str2
                        +"','"+str3+"','"+str4+"','"+str5+"','"+str6+"');");
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add quotes around the values, as in:

```
mydatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO SPENT (date,value,label1,label2,label3,label4,label5) VALUES('"+unixTime+"','"+str1+"','"+str2+"','"+str3+"','"+str4+"','"+str5+"','"+str6+"');");
```